# Problema com "ifelse" - object cannot be coerced to type 'double

Tags: r

Boa tarde. Andei pesquisando sobre o erro, mas não encontrei uma solução.

Tentei transformar o objeto `a` mas não obtive sucesso.

Alguma dica?

Estou com o seguinte problema:

```
class(ativos)
[1] "xts" "zoo"

model_list <- lapply(ativos, function(x)
lm(BBAS3 ~ x, data = ativos))

resid_list <- lapply(model_list, residuals)
lapply(resid_list, summary)

f <- function(residuals){
  z <- (residuals - mean(residuals))/sd(residuals)
  return(z)}
a <- lapply(resid_list, f)

a_if <- ifelse(a <= -2,
               "Z",
               "N")

Error in ifelse(a <= -2, "Z", "N") : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Obrigado.

EDIT: Peço desculpa a falta de informações.

`dput(head(ativos, 5))`

````
structure(c(66124.53, 66967.64, 66712.88, 67975.58, 67814.24, 
17.14, 17.25, 17.38, 18.02, 17.97, 31.18, 31.38, 31.48, 31.86, 
32.89, 26.12, 26.07, 25.87, 26.36, 26.31, 26.86, 26.93, 26.77, 
27.35, 27.26, 27.57, 28.53, 28.16, 28.85, 29.5, 21.8, 23.47, 
22.96, 22.82, 22.61, 43.2, 42.77, 43.2, 43.96, 43.9, 33.95, 33.95, 
33.89, 32.82, 33.14, 13.32, 13.13, 13.03, 13.39, 13.22, 13.16, 
13.05, 13, 13.1, 12.91, 17.28, 17.95, 18.1, 18.3, 18.45, 23.02, 
23.33, 23.12, 23.97, 24.23, 8.66, 8.92, 8.98, 9.61, 9.9, 32.57, 
33.27, 32.35, 33.43, 34.86, 41.95, 41.62, 42.12, 42.55, 42.4, 
27.11, 27.75, 27.34, 28.1, 27.9, 14.14, 13.86, 13.67, 13.67, 
13.41, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.16, 9.28, 9.35, 9.42, 9.49, 29.72, 29.86, 
29.43, 29.89, 29.72, 22.63, 22.86, 22.17, 22.32, 22.15, 26.7, 
26.75, 25.75, 25.71, 25.32, 18.12, 18.35, 18.31, 18.34, 18.1, 
13.89, 13.85, 13.71, 13.95, 13.92, 57.19, 57.39, 57.5, 58, 59.58, 
14.7, 14.85, 15.02, 15, 14.85, 20.37, 20.88, 20.88, 20.69, 20.64, 
12.89, 13.3, 13.14, 13.36, 13.46, 5.65, 5.71, 5.65, 5.83, 5.96, 
6.95, 7.11, 7.32, 7.8, 8.22, 28.59, 28.8, 28.46, 29.04, 27.8, 
30.95, 31.54, 31.3, 31.68, 31.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.84, 8.82, 8.78, 
9.12, 9.09, 23.43, 23.17, 23.11, 23.92, 23.65, 12.06, 12.15, 
12.01, 12.2, 12.18, 15.29, 15.28, 15.56, 16.06, 15.8, 13.08, 
13.1, 13.36, 13.6, 13.55, 17, 17, 16.8, 16.2, 16.3, 22.47, 22.57, 
23.09, 23.54, 23.54, 17.29, 19, 18.69, 19.25, 19.5, 7.2, 7.38, 
7.34, 7.35, 7.22, 14, 13.72, 13.72, 13.83, 13.9, 22.42, 22.42, 
22.23, 22.39, 22, 26.56, 26.94, 26.68, 27.17, 26.82, 57.91, 57.53, 
57.39, 58.91, 58.45, 16.35, 16.56, 16.81, 16.86, 16.97, 15.58, 
15.62, 15.82, 15.84, 15.86, 19.9, 20.55, 20.18, 20.1, 19.95, 
64, 63.24, 63.57, 65.99, 64.65, 8.34, 8.7, 8.55, 8.74, 8.8, 12.35, 
12.35, 12.86, 12.93, 12.62, 34.49, 35.56, 34.25, 35.7, 34.89, 
32.86, 33.99, 33.3, 34.38, 33.76, 53.1, 54.7, 54.32, 56.38, 59.25, 
20.56, 20.14, 19.7, 20, 20.39, 21.3, 21.86, 21.45, 21.54, 21.83, 
9.68, 9.6, 9.69, 9.94, 9.82, 67.01, 67, 66.6, 68.81, 68.69, 5.37, 
5.44, 5.45, 5.52, 5.46, 32.8, 35.81, 34.4, 33.82, 33.77, 47.6, 
47.5, 46.95, 47.28, 46.7, 3.71, 3.75, 3.7, 3.62, 3.65, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 12.55, 12.65, 12.61, 13.09, 12.88), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1486684800, 
1486944000, 1487030400, 1487116800, 1487203200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(5L, 
66L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("IBOV", "ABEV3", "BBAS3", "BBDC3", 
"BBDC4", "BBSE3", "BRAP4", "BRFS3", "BRKM5", "BRML3", "BTOW3", 
"CCRO3", "CIEL3", "CMIG4", "CPLE6", "CSAN3", "CVCB3", "CYRE3", 
"DOLFUT", "ECOR3", "EGIE3", "ELET3", "ELET6", "EMBR3", "ENBR3", 
"EQTL3", "ESTC3", "FLRY3", "GGBR4", "GOAU4", "GOLL4", "HYPE3", 
"IGTA3", "INDFUT", "ITSA4", "ITUB3", "JBSS3", "KLBN11", "KROT3", 
"LAME4", "LREN3", "MGLU3", "MRFG3", "MRVE3", "MULT3", "NATU3", 
"PCAR4", "PETR3", "PETR4", "QUAL3", "RADL3", "RAIL3", "RENT3", 
"SANB11", "SBSP3", "SMLS3", "SUZB3", "TAEE11", "TIMP3", "UGPA3", 
"USIM5", "VALE3", "VIVT4", "VVAR3", "WDOFUT", "WEGE3")))```
````

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(ativos)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(ativos, 20))`?

Comment: Peço desculpas pela qualidade da pergunta, adicionei informações para que seja mais reproduzível.

Answer (score 2):

O objeto `a` é de classe `"list"` porque é o resultado do `lapply` da instrução anterior. Então, é só aplicar `lapply` mais uma vez.

```
a_if <- lapply(a, function(.a) ifelse(.a <= -2, "Z", "N"))
```

Se quiser ter outra forma que não uma lista, veja, por exemplo, `sapply`.

```
a_if2 <- sapply(a, function(.a) ifelse(.a <= -2, "Z", "N"))
class(a_if2)
#[1] "matrix"
```

Comment: ,muito obrigado pela resposta. É possível utilizar o mesmo código ```a_if <- lapply(a, function(.a) ifelse(.a <= -2, "Z", "N"))``` para reproduzir outro ```ifelse```mas com o valor "-2" positivo dessa vez?

Comment: @GabrielGuilherme Não é só mudar o valor na instrução para o novo valor (positivo)?